# In which thread do CompletableFuture's completion handlers execute?

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future, forkjoinpool

I have a question about CompletableFuture method:

```
public <U> CompletableFuture<U> thenApply(Function<? super T, ? extends U> fn)
```

The thing is the JavaDoc says just this:

> Returns a new CompletionStage that, when this stage completes
> normally, is executed with this stage's result as the argument to the
> supplied function. See the CompletionStage documentation for rules
> covering exceptional completion.

What about threading? In which thread is this going to be executed? What if the future is completed by a thread pool?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The policies as specified in the [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) docs could help you understand better:

> - Actions supplied for dependent completions of non-async methods may be
>     performed by the *thread that completes the current CompletableFuture*,
>     *or by any other caller of a completion method*.
> - All async methods without an explicit Executor argument are performed
>     using the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()` (unless it does not support a
>     *parallelism level of at least two, in which case, a new Thread is
>     created to run each task*). To simplify monitoring, debugging, and
>     tracking, all generated asynchronous tasks are instances of the marker
>     interface `CompletableFuture.AsynchronousCompletionTask`.

***Update***: I would also advice on reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46062939/1746118) by @Mike as an interesting analysis further into the details of the documentation.

Comment: For methods like `thenApply`, `thenRun` what's expained in the doc is clear engough. But what about `allOf`, for something like `fa = CompletableFuture.allOf(f0, f1, f2); fa.thenRun(someRunnable)`, assume `f0`, `f1`, `f2` are completed in thread A, thread B, thread C respectively, then which thread will `someRunnable` be executed in? Again, what about `thenCompose(Function<? super T,? extends CompletionStage<U>> fn)` in case like `f0.thenCompose(x -> someNewCompletionStageProducer).thenRun(someRunnable)`, `someRunnable` will be executed in thread of `f0` or  the future returned by `fn`? @Naman

Answer (score 63):

As [@nullpointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46060587/175070) points out, the documentation tells you what you need to know.  However, the relevant text is surprisingly vague, and some of the comments (and answers) posted here seem to rely on assumptions that aren't supported by the documentation.  Thus, I think it's worthwhile to pick it apart.  Specifically, we should read this paragraph very carefully:

> Actions supplied for dependent completions of non-async methods may be performed by the thread that completes the current CompletableFuture, or by any other caller of a completion method.

Sounds straightforward enough, but it's light on details.  It seemingly deliberately avoids describing *when* a dependent completion may be invoked on the completing thread versus during a call to a completion method like `thenApply`.  As written, the paragraph above is practically *begging* us to fill in the gaps with assumptions.  That's dangerous, especially when the topic concerns concurrent and asynchronous programming, where many of the expectations we've developed as programmers get turned on their head.  Let's take a careful look at what the documentation **doesn't** say.

The documentation does **not** claim that dependent completions registered *before* a call to `complete()` will run on the completing thread.  Moreover, while it states that a dependent completion *might* be invoked when calling a completion method like `thenApply`, it **does not** state that a completion will be invoked **on the thread that registers it** (note the words "any other").

These are potentially important points for anyone using `CompletableFuture` to schedule and compose tasks.  Consider this sequence of events:

1. Thread A registers a dependent completion via `f.thenApply(c1)`.
2. Some time later, Thread B calls `f.complete()`.
3. Around the same time, Thread C registers another dependent completion via `f.thenApply(c2)`.

Conceptually, `complete()` does two things: it publishes the result of the future, and then it attempts to invoke dependent completions.  Now, what happens if Thread C runs *after* the result value is posted, but *before* Thread B gets around to invoking `c1`?  Depending on the implementation, Thread C may see that `f` has completed, and it may then invoke `c1` *and* `c2`.  Alternatively, Thread C may invoke `c2` while leaving Thread B to invoke `c1`.  The documentation does not rule out either possibility.  With that in mind, here are assumptions that **are not supported** by the documentation:

1. That a dependent completion `c` registered on `f` *prior to completion* will be invoked during the call to `f.complete()`;
2. That `c` will have run to completion by the time `f.complete()` returns;
3. That dependent completions will be invoked in any particular order (e.g., order of registration);
4. That dependent completions registered *before* `f` completes will be invoked before completions registered *after* `f` completes.

Consider another example:

1. Thread A calls `f.complete()`;
2. Some time later, Thread B registers a completion via `f.thenApply(c1)`;
3. Around the same time, Thread C registers a separate completion via `f.thenApply(c2)`.

If it is known that `f` has already run to completion, one might be tempted to assume that `c1` will be invoked during `f.thenApply(c1)` and that `c2` will be invoked during `f.thenApply(c2)`.  One might further assume that `c1` will have run to completion by the time `f.thenApply(c1)` returns.  However, the documentation **does not** support these assumptions.  It may be possible that *one* of the threads calling `thenApply` ends up invoking *both* `c1` and `c2`, while the other thread invokes neither.

A careful analysis of the JDK code could determine how the hypothetical scenarios above might play out.  But even that is risky, because you may end up relying on an implementation detail that is (1) not portable, or (2) subject to change.  Your best bet is not to assume anything that's not spelled out in the javadocs or the original JSR spec.

**tldr:** Be careful what you assume, and when you write documentation, be as clear and deliberate as possible.  While brevity is a wonderful thing, be wary of the human tendency to fill in the gaps.

Comment: Interesting analysis - really digs into the intricacies of implementation promises in the realm of concurrent programming.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks!  I found the documentation to be carefully worded yet curiously vague, which sent me into "paranoid analysis" mode.  I was also amused that the accepted answer made no attempt to decipher or otherwise expand upon the quoted Javadocs, which was probably wise :).

Comment: It seems that in the past, I should have asked myself what “completion method” actually means when I read that documentation. “A careful analysis of the JDK code” leads to the conclusion that most of the surprising scenarios you describe, are indeed possible. So the risk to rely on implementation details is rather low. The fact that two independent actions have no ordering, hence, are not executed in the order they were registered, has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37919561/2711488) already, though that didn’t even require the more surprising scenarios you describe.

Comment: @Holger I rather dislike the way they use 'completion' to describe a task that runs upon completion of its antecedent.  Because that word appears rather often when discussing futures ("completion of", "having run to completion", etc.), it's easy to gloss over or misinterpret it in contexts like that javadoc excerpt.  I would have preferred they use 'continuation' instead.

Comment: Yeah, when I read it the first time, I thought that “a completion method” meant either of `complete`, `completeExceptionally`, `cancel`, or `obtrude…` as these *complete* rather than *chain* or define or continuation…

Comment: @Holger I think it _generally_ refers to those, and concurrent calls to `complete` and `cancel`, for example, imply a similar race to the one I described between `complete` and `thenApply`.  It's possible that "completion method" in the quoted excerpt was not meant to _directly_ include chaining methods like `thenApply`.  However, those chaining methods lead to `tryFire` being called, and the code comments explicitly identify `tryFire` as a "completion method", so they would still be _transitively_ covered.  The more I look at this, the more I think the documentation is just terrible.

Comment: I don't fully understand your answer. I appreciate you highlighting what the specification does **not** guarantee, but can you please clarify the other side of the coin as well? Specifically, can you provide examples of which threads **are** allowed to execute non-async completions? I am having a hard time imagining what these can be. Thank you.

Comment: That is the point of the answer. The doc outlined a few choices the implementation can freely choose from wherever it sees fit: any thread that registers the thenApply, or thread that completes the completionStage. You can't assume what the implementation does.

Comment: If you really need to specify which thread to run the thenApply, then use thenApplyAsync. It is the same thing except you can control which executor to use.

Comment: `or by any other caller of a completion method` does this even include callers of such methods on other, unrelated CompletableFuture objects?

Comment: @phant0m no, it does not apply to entirely unrelated futures.

Answer (score 10):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html):

> Actions supplied for dependent completions of non-async methods may be performed by the thread that completes the current CompletableFuture, or by any other caller of a completion method.

More concretely:

- `fn` will run during the call to `complete()` in the context of whichever thread has called `complete()`.
- If `complete()` has already finished by the time `thenApply()` is called, `fn` will be run in the context of the thread calling `thenApply()`.

Answer (score 6):

When it comes to threading the API documentation is lacking. It takes a bit of inference to understand how threading and futures work. Start with one assumption: the non-`Async` methods of `CompletableFuture` do not spawn new threads on their own. Work will proceed under existing threads.

`thenApply` will run in the original `CompletableFuture`'s thread. That's either the thread that calls `complete()`, or the one that calls `thenApply()` if the future is already completed. If you want control over the thread—a good idea if `fn` is a slow operation—then you should use `thenApplyAsync`.

Comment: Not quite clear original thread. What if the the future is completed by a standalone thread pool? For instance, we execute some computation in the pool and when it's finished just call `CompletableFuture::complete`.

Comment: Also note the corner case where the `CompletableFuture` completes before the `thenApply` call returns - in this case, because the `CompletableFuture` is completed; it will execute on the _current_ thread.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I want to use source code to explain this question.

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> thenAccept(Consumer<? super T> action) {
    return uniAcceptStage(null, action);
}

private CompletableFuture<Void> uniAcceptStage(Executor e,
                                               Consumer<? super T> f) {
    if (f == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    Object r;
    if ((r = result) != null)
        return uniAcceptNow(r, e, f);
    CompletableFuture<Void> d = newIncompleteFuture();
    unipush(new UniAccept<T>(e, d, this, f));
    return d;
}
```

This is the source code from java 16, and we can see, if we trigger thenAccept, we will pass a null executor service reference into our function.
From the 2nd function uniAcceptStage() 2nd if condition. If result is not null, it will trigger uniAcceptNow()

```
if (e != null) {
     e.execute(new UniAccept<T>(null, d, this, f));
} else {
     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") T t = (T) r;
     f.accept(t);
     d.result = NIL;
}
```

if executor service is null, we will use lambda function f.accept(t) to execute it. If we are triggering this thenApply/thenAccept from main thread, it will use main thread as executing thread.

But if we cannot get previous result from last completablefuture, we will push our current UniAccept/Apply into stack by using uniPush function. And UniAccept class has tryFire() which will be triggered from our postComplete() function

```
final void postComplete() {
    /*
     * On each step, variable f holds current dependents to pop
     * and run.  It is extended along only one path at a time,
     * pushing others to avoid unbounded recursion.
     */
    CompletableFuture<?> f = this; Completion h;
    while ((h = f.stack) != null ||
           (f != this && (h = (f = this).stack) != null)) {
        CompletableFuture<?> d; Completion t;
        if (STACK.compareAndSet(f, h, t = h.next)) {
            if (t != null) {
                if (f != this) {
                    pushStack(h);
                    continue;
                }
                NEXT.compareAndSet(h, t, null); // try to detach
            }
            f = (d = h.tryFire(NESTED)) == null ? this : d;
        }
    }
}
```