# CompletableFuture thenApply is running in seperate thread not on caller thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, completable-future

When I execute `thenApply` method of a `CompletableFuture`, the execution of this method is happening in the `ForkJoinPool` thread, not on caller (main) thread. **Why is it so?** This result i.e using the fork join pool instead of caller thread is similar to when calling `thenApplyAsync`, so I want to understand the reason behind this behavior of `thenApply`

```
        System.out.println("hello world, CompletableFuturesRightHere");
        System.out.println("log1: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        CompletableFuture<Integer> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            System.out.println("log-sA: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return 40;
        }).thenApply( a ->  {
            System.out.println("log-tA: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return a + 40;
        });

        System.out.println("log3: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("cf result: " + cf.get());
```

below is output of above code:

```
hello world, CompletableFuturesRightHere
log1: main
log-sA: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
log3: main
log-tA: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3
cf result: 80
```

When I run the [same code](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/FkU) in jdoodle, the behavior is as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CompletableFuture` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) states

> Actions supplied for dependent completions of non-async methods may be performed by the thread that completes the current CompletableFuture, or by any other caller of a completion method.

This covers both behaviors you describe; either, the original thread from the fork join pool is reused ("ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3" in your output) for the following completion stage, or the calling thread is used after the previous stage finishes.

Using `thenApplyAsync` would be able to use a different thread from the common pool.

Comment: i did look at the method documentation, but thank for pointing out above point that is documented at class level.

Comment: `or by **any other** caller of a completion method.` <- would you mind to elaborate on this. It seems to point to more than just the caller (main) thread.

Comment: @samshers I understand it to mean "in any thread of the current call stack", ie if you do `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync().thenApplyAsync().thenApplyAsync().thenApply()`, the last call will be performed in either of the (up to) three threads used by the previous ones, but never a new one. But that's my interpretation, not an authoritative answer.

Comment: @samshers [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46062939/2711488) elaborates on the meaning of “any other caller of a completion method”. The takeaway is that using `thenApply` instead of `thenApplyAsync` implies *the least control* over the executing thread imaginable.